# Deleting file from batch file giving error

Tags: batch-file

I am facing error when i try to delete a file using a batch file.
For example say the file i want to delete is "C:\test\a.dll"

i get the folder "c:\test" from registry and then i try to append the file name using and delete it using the following command

del /s %WPINSTDIR%\a.dll

where i get WPINSTDIR from registry and it would be "C:\test"

however when i try to run the batch file i get a error saying network path found
and this is the command that is executed.
del /s "c:\test"\a.dll

By setting a environment path variable i found that the problem is with the 2 slashes in "c:\test" and the quotes. Anyway to get around this problem.

Thanks

Comment: By 2 slashes i mean the WPINSTDIR is coming as "C:\\test"

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
pushd %WPINSTDIR%
del /s a.dll
popd
```

This restores the former directory.

Comment: i just tried this and it seems to work. Need to check all scenarios. Thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 0):

This might do:

```
set current=%CD%
CD /d %WPINSTDIR%
DEL /s a.dll
CD /d %current%
```

**EDIT**
Edited to use `CD /d` and the "`%CD%`-trick".

Comment: Works only if the current drive is equal to the drive in %WPINSTDIR%.

Comment: Frank: You can use `cd /d` then.

Comment: well i tried that and it does work but since my batch file is a part of a patch after deleting the file i need to go back to the original drive where the files were temporarily copied for the patch to execute and this path is selected by user i cant go ahead with this solution. ANy other means?

Comment: You can use `pushd` then to change the directory instead and after deleting `popd` to restore the original directory.

Comment: Meh, poor man's clone of `pushd`/`popd`. I'd use those since it's clearer what they do. And they work even without command extensions.

Comment: Didn't know whether `pushd/popd` actually supported changing the drive then `cd`ing. Now I know ;-)

Comment: You can even `pushd` UNC paths, when command extensions are enabled (which is the default anyway) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quotes around your environment variable with the following:

```
%WPINSTDIR:"=%
```

So the following might work:

```
del %WPINSTDIR:"=%\a.dll
```

It will fail, though, if the path contains spaces.

You can also use the following:

```
call :del_file %WPINSTDIR% a.dll
goto :eof
:del_file
del "%~1\%~2"
goto :eof
```

which should work even with paths containing spaces. The `~` in `%~1` removes surrounding quotes.